# Objective C: Regex 2 different input possibilities

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, input

I have an input form which is supposed to take two different input forms and validate them.

The first should be a digit input which starts with two 77 and is then followed by other numbers which can be from 0 to 9. The total length can be 13.

i.e: 77XXXXXXXXXXX

The second input form is 3 digits[0-9] followed by a dot and then 3 numbers again this can be repeated for a total of 12 numbers.

i.e. XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

The second part works --> `"[0-9]{3}(?:.[0-9]{3}){3}$"`

The first part for some reason won't work --> `"7{2}[0-9]{13}"`

E: After some testing, I have found out that only the second test gets validated. 
Any suggestions to combine those two checks? If it isn't one to check for the other.

Comment: Provide sample input for first part which is not passing the regex test

Comment: the input would be 7770093450509. The third 7 is just there in this example and not necessarily in others.

Comment: Ok, the total length _can_ _be_ 13. So maximum it can have 13 digits right? It can have less than 13 also?

Comment: yeah please clarify on "can be 13" and "can be repeated for a total of 12 numbers"

Comment: The first part that is not working consists of 12 numbers without any dots in between. The other part that I got to work consists of 13 numbers in total with 3 dots in between the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the first part:

```
^77\d{11}$
```

and, for the second part:

```
^\d{3}(?:\.\d{3}){3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

since

> the total lenght can be 13

you have to use 11 at the end, because the number of unknown digit is 11:

```
"7{2}[0-9]{11}"
```

note that your regex for the second part "works" but not so much, for example it parses a lot more: the `.` is regarded as a jolly character in regular expressions, so it matches for example

```
"346m111o555m333"
```

also, what you mean by "can be 13" or "can be repeated"? It can not? Because if it doesn't, neither your regex will work

You can use this instead:

```
"77\d{11}"
```

for the first part and

```
"\d{3}(?:\.\d{3}){3}"
```

for the second

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

"(7{2}[0-9]{11})|([0-9]{3}(?:.[0-9]{3}){3}$)|([0-9]{12})"

First part matches for numbers starting with 77 followed with numbers from 0-9 and a maximum of 13 digits.

Second part check for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and the last part for the same just without the . in between.

All other inputs throw an error(at least here)

Thank you everybody